# Named Credential ignores authorization header in apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, security, httprequest

I have created a named credential, `myNamedCredential`, where Generate Authorization Header is `True`. When I look at the codebase, we have a trigger with code that will set the `Authorization Header` using some logic when making an external callout. When reviewing SFDC documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_custom_headers_bodies.htm), I see that when the `Authorization Header` is set in code then we should deselect `Generate Authorization Header`.

**What I have observed**

1. When `Generate Authorization Header` is set to `true` then the named credential authorization takes precedence over the `Authorization` header set in code
2. When `Generate Authorization Header` is set to false then the `Authorization` header set in code is used

**Questions**

1. Why does the `Authorization` header from the named credential take precedence over the Authorization header set in code?
2. Shouldn't this setting give an error message? (I am surprised it has not thrown an error)

Comment: What you have observed does not contradict the documentation...?

Comment: @identigral i don't know that "contradict" is the right term here. I am not sure what is but it doesn't seem to be consistent with sfdc documentation, which is throwing me off. Logically if both are set (one in code and another in named credential) there would be some options to pick that take precedence but maybe named credentials to take precedence over apex code? I can't find any documentation though to state that named credential authorization header takes precedence.

Comment: By the very definition of NC, precedence in #1 should be on NC side. Encapsulation of a security primitive and resulting behavior shouldn't be "silently" modifiable via code. Thus override requires an explicit action by the operator (option #2). As a corollary, one can infer expected behavior of #1 as being the opposite of #2. The latter is explicitly spelled out in the doc. Agreed that this should be better documented.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the Authorization header from the named credential take precedence over the Authorization header set in code?

We can't necessarily answer why, but presumably, it allows an override for whatever the code may be doing. Note that all elements outside of Name, Label, and Endpoint are **subscriber editable** (in terms of Managed Packages). This means they can override your authentication mechanism, which can be useful if they need to change the header for some reason.

> Shouldn't this setting give an error message? (I am surprised it has thrown an error)

No. Subscribers can change the authentication post-install, so they need to be able to potentially override the setting. As such, it wouldn't make sense to break an installed package just because the subscriber changed the Authentication header.

Comment: It seems as though the precedence is given to the named credential and maybe it's a miss in sfdc documentation?

Comment: @usernameabc Yeah, I'd say it's a gap in documentation.